# ImportError: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory，

Tags: python, linux, pygrib

The problem occurred： ImportError: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory，when I install pygrib on linux(centOS6) by Anaconda

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygrib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> exit()
================================================================
[root@localhost ll]# locate libhdf5.so.101
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

Please help me,thank you!

Comment: The locate error doesn't mean that you don't have the file, it means that you haven't created the locate database. Try running `updatedb` as root. There should be a cron job that does this too in /etc/cron.daily/ but I guess it's disabled.

Comment: I'd try `yum info *hdf*` to see if CentOS provide any HDF packages. If not you'll either have to find an RPM from somewhere else (that's built for CentOS 7, or compatible, e.g. maybe ScientificLinux), or build it yourself.

Comment: I will try do it, thank you!

Comment: I have installed hdf5-1.8.17, but it has not found the Packages about hdf when I input "yum info *hdf*" . And nothing happened when i update the db and input " locate libhdf5.so.101 ". Thanks for your  answer.